# Enable touches only in upper view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a view controller in which i am adding some menu subview on top of .
Than i have buttons on this menu , hence i have to disable touches on the main view, and enable them on the subview menu.

I have tried that from the subview class(which is `UIView` subclass) :

```
self.superview.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
self.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
sideMenuBackView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
```

Where the button is added to the  `sideMenuBackView` , and is not fired when hit .

How would i enable buttons in a subview class.

EDIT:

I saw this :

```
-(id)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    id hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (hitView == self) return nil;
    else return hitView;
}
```

which i don't really help because if i put it in the parent view it will disable touches for ever and not temporary. what i need is to temporary enable touches to buttons in a subview, and disable touches in its parent view. than when menu is closed, enable again the parent

Comment: Why would you want userInteractionDisabled on a UIView (aka the superview).

Comment: If you disable user interaction on a view, it affects all the subviews. You may need to individually disable specific subviews.

Answer (score 0):

make object like       View *myview;

if you want to hide then

self.myview.hidden=YES;

Comment: you mention that you have to disable parent view then you can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Capture all touch events in the superview, then use `UITouch -locationInView` to determine which subview the touch was in.  Ignore any touches that aren't in the subview you want active.  Pass touches in the desired subview on to the subview to handle them.

e.g.:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([self.subView1 pointInside:[touch locationInView:self.subView1] withEvent:nil])
    {
        // User touched inside the subview - pass the event on to that subview to handle it           
        [self.subView1 touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }
    else
    {
        // User touched a different subview or in the main (superview) - ignore the touch
    }
}
```

Do the same in `-touchesMoved` and `-touchesEnded`.

Comment: this is a problem for me, because if i add this function to the super view, it will stay there forever, and i need to disable touches in the superview only temporary when a menu is open above it.

Comment: Set a flag when your menu is opened.  Put the code above inside an `if` block.  Pass the touches to the subview when the flag is set.  Pass them on to [super] when it isn't

Comment: yes thats what i did . but it think its a bad practice ,because if i wanted to write a class that its a menu view to be added to any other class, this will be a bad implementation and a non capsulated object.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass your my view and implement this:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    return CGRectContainsPoint(self.button.frame, point);
}
```

will allow button touchable but prevent all other touch.